# Do any of the non-human characters in Harry Potter have surnames?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

It strikes me that non-humans occupy a rather subservient position in the universe of Harry Potter, at least as far as their names go. The human characters (Muggles and magicians alike) are typically given a forename **and** a surname, as is the normal custom in the real world. There may be characters like Yaxley and Travers who are only referred to by one name but presumably they *have* first names even if they are widely known by their surnames.

Non-humans, on the other hand, seem to be universally given one name and one name only. Out of the multiple examples I could cite we have:

> **Kreacher    Dobby    Winky   
>   Hokey    Griphook   
>
>   Bogrod    Firenze    Bane    Ronan    Magorian    Grawp   
>
>   Hedwig    Crookshank    Buckbeak    Aragog    Fluffy, etc.**

Now some of these characters are little more than pets, animals with no distinct personality who never say a word. But many of them are autonomous, intelligent and distinctive beings. Centaurs, for instance, are a proud and independent species - many of whom regard themselves as the *superiors* of wizards and witches. They cannot go by single names out of any sense of inferiority.

**Is there a non-human character I missed who is known by two names? Is there any reason (in-universe *or* out-of-universe) that explains why non-humans seemingly only have one name and one name only?**

---

**Boundaries:** I'm discounting ghosts since they *used* to be known by two or more names but have in many cases been given an nickname after death. Moaning Myrtle and other ghost names don't count. Similarly, I'm ruling out Fenrir Greyback. He may have two names and be a werewolf but since werewolves are also humans (at least most of the time) he doesn't meet my criteria.

Comment: Rubeus Hagrid is only half human but is treated as a human so probably doesn't count.

Comment: Some toads have last names (i.e. Dolores Umbridge) however, Trevor and many other important toads are neglected in terms of last names.

Comment: Also vampires; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Vampires

Comment: [Mrs Norris?](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mrs_Norris)

Comment: Hey, congrats on 10k!

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Cheers. It's been a tough month.

Comment: ["Moaning" Myrtle Warren](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Myrtle_Warren) is her full name.

Comment: @Gallifreyan. Muchos gracias!

Comment: @Valorum Mrs Norris counts as a surname I guess. She still only has one name, however. Ideally I'm looking for a character with a first name *and* a surname.

Comment: As for why, I think it's a bit that they're subservient but also because it's just a human thing to have two names. Other creatures just don't seem to follow that tradition.

Comment: Presumably Flitwick and Fleur don't count as they are mostly human but have a dash of something else too?

Comment: @ThruGog Yeah, I'm not really thinking of mixed race people.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked for characters with several names which are nonhuman for some time and found none.

The reason seems to be to highlight different cultures with possible connotations which can be deduced.

In the case of proud Centaurs and likely Goblins too, it seems they have an inherently different culture and would be vehemently against copying human/wizard conventions when they found out about them. (Note two names are a very human thing; would aliens be expected to follow this? Initially starting life differently, should other sentient life follow the same naming conventions?)

In the case of House Elves, I have suggested before that one name highlights the idea that they are beneath humans/wizards. I argued then that a race enslaved hardly needs family names as they may not even come across their own kind often - there's less need for the identification that our naming system provides. [Do House Elves have last names?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144269/do-house-elves-have-last-names/145194#145194)